# Boxing Native C++ Pointer

Tags: .net, pointers, c++-cli, native, boxing

I have a pointer to a native class and want to temporarily wrap it in a Object. I assume the System::Reflection::Pointer::Box() function would be the way to go. However I'm having trouble formatting the second parameter to it.

```
class A {}
A * a;
Object ^ o = Box(a, A::typeid);
```

I get a runtime error that says 'Type must be a pointer', as I suppose it should be. But I cannot figure out the syntax.

Comment: This is C++/CLI, not C++, right?

Comment: yes. (hmm.. 15 character minimum for a comment, who'd have thunk it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get `System.Reflection.Pointer.Box` to work either, but found the capability to do what you are trying with humble `IntPtr`.

```
A * a = new A;
Object ^o = gcnew IntPtr(a); // a is boxed in o
IntPtr i = safe_cast<IntPtr>(o); // Unbox the IntPtr
A * aIsBack = static_cast<A*>(i.ToPointer()); // Retrieve a
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quiet as elegant as Box(), but nothing a pre-processing directive can't fix.